# imported typescript enum doesn't work in compiled output

Tags: typescript, enums, typescript-typings

I'm trying to create a collection of enums to be used inside an index.ts file. Rather than keeping these enums directly inside the index.ts file, I want to import them from another file.

To do this, I tried declaring a namespace inside a declaration file:

```
declare namespace reservedWords {
  enum Variables {
    const = 'const',
    let = 'let',
    var = 'var',
  }
  ...
  // more enums and other things
}

export default reservedWords;
```

I then try to import this in the index.ts file:

```
import reservedWords from 'reservedWords.d.ts';

...

if (thing === reservedWords.Variables.const) doSomething();
```

Before compiling, I tried to add my `src` directory to my typeroots since that's where I'm keeping the reservedWords.d.ts file:

```
    "typeRoots" : ["./src", "./node_modules/@types"],
```

When I compile the index.ts file with `tsc`, I'm seeing that the compiled index.js file is saying that it's importing `reservedWords`, but nothing with that name exists in the bin (export) folder.

```js
import reservedWords from 'reservedWords';
```

How can I get the index.ts file to use these enums? Not sure how necessary using a namespace is, but I figured organizing these enums inside a namespace in a declaration file would be the best thing to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to `export` the `enums`

```
declare namespace reservedWords {
  export enum Variables {
    const = 'const',
    let = 'let',
    var = 'var',
  }
  ...
  // more enums and other things
}

export default reservedWords;
```

And under `index.ts`

```
    import * as reservedWords from 'reservedWords'
```

Comment: How would `Variables` be used from index.ts like this?

Comment: reservedWords.Variables.const

Answer (score 1):

You may be looking for the constant enums. This typescript feature will help you to generate enum values in requested places. Here's an example for your case:

```
const enum Variables {
  const = 'const',
  let = 'let',
  var = 'var',
}
```

More details could be found in the [official documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#const-enums).

P.S.: I suppose there's no need to use `import reservedWords from 'reservedWords.d.ts';` as you already specified type type roots.